# Is it possible to start a VNC server in Ubuntu in display 0 without using the default VNC server Vino?

Tags: vnc, ubuntu-9.04

Is it possible to start a VNC server in Ubuntu in display 0 without using default VNC server Vino?

My intention is I don't want the notification in the machine running VNC server when one client is connected to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to do this with tightvnc.

```
sudo apt-get install tightvncserver

sudo apt-get install xtightvncviewer
```

You have to start the server process in a shell (typically ssh) before you can connect with a client. You can also use any vnc client to connect, for instance I use a windows vnc client for this.

Comment: hi .. but i can't setup vncserver in display 0


suresh@suresh-desktop:/media/backup$ tightvncserver :0

Warning: suresh-desktop:0 is taken because of /tmp/.X0-lock
Remove this file if there is no X server suresh-desktop:0
A VNC server is already running as :0
but no vino or vnc processes are running in background

Answer (score 2):

I use x11vnc, for similar result:
ssh remotehost
( export DISPLAY=:0; x11vnc -shared -forever -usepw -ncache 10)

you get the idea. hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

If the intent is not to receive notification, you can turn it off in vino.
Go to System->Preferences->Remote Desktop. Choose the settings to turn it off.
In the Advanced  tab, there is an option to turn off the notification icons as well.

Answer (score 0):

Rfb will export the current display without needing to restart X etc.
(It seems only krfb is available in recent ubuntus, so you'll need to install all sorts of kde libs - I guess the vanilla rfb isnt actively developed, shame.)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want the VNC server on display 0, and you don't want to use x11vnc or something similar to mirror another X server, you're going to have to shut down the X server that's running on display 0 (probably launched by gdm), or configure it to run on another display.